# Array-OutOfBound Exception in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview

i'm new to android and got stuck up in horizontal swipe. let me explain in detail, i have couple of datas in `ListView` if the user clicks the `ListView` item- Detailed description page gets opened, here i need to swipe the "Detailed Description" page horizontally. i downloaded and tested some of the tutorials using pageIndicator library. finally was able to get `ListView` data but when clicked on list item it gets force close, the error in logcat says `OutOfBound Exception`  Please help me, thanks.

Logcat Exception

```
01-22 12:28:46.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1084): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 12:28:46.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1084): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
01-22 12:28:46.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
01-22 12:28:46.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
01-22 12:28:46.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at com.jokes.LayoutTwo.onCreateView(LayoutTwo.java:70)
 01-22 12:28:46.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
01-22 12:28:46.530: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
```

LayoutTwo.java

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.samples, null);

         TextView txttitle = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.titles);
  ///////// The exception arises in below line ///////
     txttitle.setText(Common.rowItems.get(Common.itemnumber).get("strtitle"));   

     TextView txtDescription = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.description);
     txtDescription.setText(Common.rowItems.get(Common.itemnumber).get("strDesc"));

     Intent in = getActivity().getIntent();        
        String strtitle = in.getStringExtra("strtitle");
        String strDesc = in.getStringExtra("strDesc");

    return root;
}
```

But i have given the array length correctly in MainActivity.
MainActivity.java

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
 for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
 RowItem item = new RowItem(titles[i], descriptions[i]);
 rowItems.add(item);
  }

  listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
 CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
    R.layout.list_item, rowItems);
  listView.setAdapter(adapter);
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
   }

 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
  long id) {
TextView txttl = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);  
String strtitle = txttl.getText().toString();


TextView txtls = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desc);   
String strDesc = txtls.getText().toString();

// Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewPagerStyle1Activity.class);
// sending data to new activity
i.putExtra("strtitle", strtitle);
i.putExtra("strDesc", strDesc);
startActivity(i);
   }
 }
```

Comment: i have given like this in MainActivity..  public static final String[] titles = new String[] { "Strawberry",
    "Banana", "Orange", "Mixed" };

public static final String[] descriptions = new String[] {
    "It is an aggregate accessory fruit",
    "It is the largest herbaceous flowering plant", "Citrus Fruit",
    "Mixed Fruits" };  @Shayanpourvatan

Comment: what is common.rawItems and where it has been initialized ?

Answer (score 1):

```
txttitle.setText(Common.rowItems.get(Common.itemnumber).get("strtitle"));
```

I guess `Common.rowItems` has not been filled by the time this line is called. So it is empty. Now `Common.itemnumber` seems to be "0". Which asks an empty structure for its first element.

To solve this, you'll have to check if `Common.itemnumber` has a reasonable value to index into `Common.rowItems` first. And if not, then set a default text or something like that. Or of course, make sure `Common.rowItems` has been filled. But you still should verify the index is not out of bounds.

Comment: To add up, I think Activity.onCreate() will trigger fragments creation, so the code in your activity to fill the array may get executed after onCreateView() of a fragment. So If you can, fill the array in static block? OR pass from previous Activity?

Answer (score 0):

use like this :

```
Intent in = getActivity().getIntent();        
String strtitle = in.getStringExtra("strtitle");
String strDesc = in.getStringExtra("strDesc");

TextView txttitle = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.titles);
TextView txtDescription = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.description);

txttitle.setText(strtitle);        
txtDescription.setText(strDesc);
```